# Given a list of tree heights find the least attempts possible to cut them down

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The question I'm trying to solve is that, imagine you have a list of the number of trees in each column, e.g. [10,20,10,0], each element in this list is the number of the trees exist in that column, means that in the first column you have ten trees, in the second column you have 20 trees and so on. The number of columns is fixed, and by cutting out a column, its number will become zero. You can cut down a row or a column completely if possible, but you can only cut down in continuous rows or columns, means that if you have [4,0,4] you cannot cut down rows in order to cut all trees down.
For [4,0,4] it just takes two attempts, cutting down first and third columns down. I'll give you another example, imagine you have a list of [4,3,4,3,4] you can cut down three rows and make it [1,0,1,0,1] but then you have to remove three columns which takes you a total of 6 steps, but also you can cut down all columns which take 5 steps, any other solution's result would be greater than 5 steps.

Edit: This image will clarify the question: 
First, you cut the column which has 4 elements, then you cut the first row, then you cut the column which has 2 elements now, and then the last row or column. As I've stated before, you cannot cut rows which have a discontinuity. (All elements present in a row should be adjacent in order to be able to cut the row down)  (in this picture, the row #3 has a discontinuity)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH8cJ.png)

I'm trying to solve this question for two days, I'm getting nowhere. My latest code is here, which goes into an almost infinite loop in non-square like [for example a list of 3 with the most element being 200] tree list.

```
    def cut_tree_row(tree):
    res = []
    discontinoue_flag = 0 # A flag to findout if cutting down the row is possible or not
    non_zero_flag_once = 0 # if the program encounters a non_zero element for the first time this would change to 1
    non_zero_flag_twice = 0# if the program encounters a non_zero element for the second time while the discontinue flag is 1, it would change to 1
    for i in xrange(len(tree)):
        if tree[i] > 0:
            non_zero_flag_once = 1
            if non_zero_flag_once == 1 and discontinoue_flag == 1:
                non_zero_flag_twice = 1
            else:
                res.append(tree[i]-1)
        else:
            if discontinoue_flag == 0 and non_zero_flag_once == 1:
                discontinoue_flag = 1
            if discontinoue_flag == 1 and non_zero_flag_twice == 1:
                return [], 10000000
            res.append(0)
    if discontinoue_flag == 1 and non_zero_flag_twice == 1:
        return [], 10000000

    return res , 1

def cut_tree_column(tree):

    res = []
    max_index = 0
    m = max(tree)
    flag = 1
    if len(tree) == 0:
        return tree , 0
    for i in xrange(len(tree)):
        if tree[i] == m and flag == 1:
            flag = 0
            res.append(0)
            continue
        res.append(tree[i])
    return res , 1


def find_min_attempts(tree, total_sum = 0):
    if len(tree) == 0:
        return total_sum
    s = sum(tree)
    if s == 0:
        return total_sum
    res1 , num1 = cut_tree_column(tree)
    res2 , num2 = cut_tree_row(tree)
    return  min(find_min_attempts(res1, total_sum + num1),find_min_attempts(res2, total_sum + num2))



def main():
    tree = [187, 264, 298, 924, 319] #This input gives me an infinite loop
    print find_min_attempts(tree)

main()
```

Comment: Your problem statement doesn't make much sense.  You have a list of tree heights, but then you talk about rows and columns and never use the word "height" again.  What do "rows" and "columns" have to do with trees and heights?  In your examples, "cutting down a column" seems to be the same thing as cutting down one whole tree, but "cutting down a row" seems to mean reducing the height of all the trees by one unit.  Can you clear this up?  What does a height of 0 mean?  How does [10, 20, 10, 0] differ from [10, 20, 10]?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've added an image and tried to state the problem better.
Cutting a column mean nullifying it, the column is still present but its value is turned to zero. A height of zero means the height of the tree which is in that column is zero, I know it sounds silly but the problem is just like this. Cutting down a row means reducing all heights by one unit if its possible to cut down the row. In the image I've added, you cannot cut the third row(from bottom) down because the third column has 2 elements and the row elements are not adjacent. /

Comment: /In my solution, I'm only cutting the first row down.

Comment: this is a pretty fascinating problem. I would request community's experienced users to take a bit time before downvoting something

Comment: @FarhoodET, I don't think a brute solution would be hard. But it looks like its from an online judge, and if that's the case, what is expected time complexity? would O(N^2) be ok?

Comment: Based on the diagram you provided, the entries in the list are not "heights" but *the number of trees in each column*.  When the problem is correctly stated, the initial list defines a 2D grid of trees.  In a single cut you remove either an entire column of trees, all of the first row (if there are no gaps) or a gap-free part of the first row (if there are gaps).  Stated this way the problem's terminology makes sense.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Agree - those who downvoted or voted to close were definitely trigger-happy.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thanks! maybe it's a bit translation problem because this problem was given to us with "tree heights" instead of the number of trees but the picture indeed points to the number of trees. I have re-edited my post.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I've tried the brute-force solution, it doesn't fit well with the time limit.(1s max when the len(list) < 1000)

Comment: What is the expected time complexity?
Taking m rows and n columns in a 2d grid, the minimum complexity would be m*n.

Answer (score 2):

This recursive solution calculates the number of steps after cutting the largest column and alternately, the largest row.  It returns the minimum of the two.

If a zero is present, it solves each discontinuous section as a subproblem.

```
def get_max_col(t):
    """ Get index of tallest column """
    return max(enumerate(t),key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

def remove_max_col(t):
    """ Remove tallest column """
    idx = get_max_col(t)
    new_t = t[:]
    new_t[idx] = 0
    return new_t

def remove_bottom_row(t):
    """ Remove bottom row """
    return [x - 1 for x in t]

def splitz(iterable, val):
    """ Split a list using val as the delimiter value """
    result = []
    group = []
    for e in iterable:
        if e == val:
            if group: # ignore empty groups 
                result.append(group)
                group = [] # start new 
        else:
            group.append(e)
    if group: # last group
        result.append(group)

    return result

def min_cuts(t):
    # All zeroes, finished
    if set(t) == set([0]):
        return 0

    # Single column
    if len(t) == 1:
        return 1

    # All ones, single row
    if set(t) == set([1]):
        return 1

    # If discontinued, add cost of subproblems
    if 0 in t:
        sub_ts = splitz(t, 0)
        return sum(map(min_cuts, sub_ts))
    # try removing the largest column and largest row(bottom)
    # Pick the cheapest one
    else:
        t1 = remove_max_col(t)
        x = 1 + min_cuts(t1)

        t2 = remove_bottom_row(t)
        y = 1 + min_cuts(t2)

        return min(x, y)

print(min_cuts([4,3,4,3,4]))
print(min_cuts([187, 264, 298, 924, 319]))
```

Comment: This appears to work, but in your second example case it's horribly inefficient.  You always have a possible solution of cutting down each column separately.  So an optimization here would be to terminate the recursion any time you reach a depth of len(t).

Comment: @Bert this solution works but is hard to explain why you're removing the column with maximum height. Example: 2 2 4 2 2 2 3, if you remove 4, first, then it takes 6 steps. If you remove 3 first, it takes 4 steps. Your solution will still give the right answer because you consider removing rows as well. The point I'm making is there is no advantage of removing the maximum height. It can be any height.

Comment: The slightly more optimized solution would be consider removing rows as per your existing logic, and compare its result with all columns and return minimum rather than removing maxHeight or anyHeight column one by one. Comparing with all columns covers all the cases and will give the correct answer.
Worst case time complexity remains the same but it saves many additional recursive calls.